# MATCH() AGAINST() not matching the second string - MySQL

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I have a MyISAM table named `links`. It has a column `searcher` which has a `FULLTEXT` index to it. 
This is my variable values:

1. ft_min_word_len = 1
2. ft_stopword_file =
3. ft_max_word_len = 84

I need to match the rows which contain both `[show]` & `[1]` in any order.
I run this query:

```
SELECT * FROM links WHERE MATCH(searcher) AGAINST('+[show] +[1]' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

But it is also matching the rows that don't contain `[1]` string. Whats the problem?

Comment: I am not familar with MySQL's FULLTEXT but what are these `[` `]` for? What about `SELECT * FROM links WHERE MATCH(searcher) AGAINST('+show +1' IN BOOLEAN MODE)`? Sry when I am totally wrong but only looked at the documentation...

Comment: I need `[` `]`. They cannot be eliminated.

Comment: Are the brackets part of the string you're looking for or are they part of syntax? Mabe you've to escape them?

Comment: They are a part of string i am findinig @Fabian Barney

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have to make clear that the brackets are part of the search string and not part of syntax for grouping expressions.

This query should work for you:

```
SELECT * FROM links WHERE MATCH(searcher) AGAINST('+"[show]" +"[1]"' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

Here are some sample fiddles:

- [not working](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1cd77/2)
- [working](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1cd77/1)